# How do I include the Python "packaging" library on build farm?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I'm confused how to properly include a requirement for the Python `packaging` library into my package.

As far as I understand, that library is called `python-packaging` in ROS, so I added it to my `package.xml`.
On my local system, it builds and runs without problems, but on the build farm, it fails with

```
05:55:04 Traceback (most recent call last):
05:55:04   File "/tmp/ws/install_isolated/ament_virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ament_virtualenv/combine_requirements.py", line 30, in <module>
05:55:04     from packaging.requirements import Requirement, InvalidRequirement
05:55:04 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packaging'
```

and

```
05:55:05 [1.060s]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
05:55:05 [1.061s]     raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
05:55:05 [1.061s] pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'packaging' distribution was not found and is required by ament-virtualenv
```

I've tried all forms of dependencies (`build_depend`, `buildtool_depend`, `exec_depend`, ...), and tried adding either `packaging` or `python-packaging` to the `install_requires` section in `setup.py` / `setup.cgf`.

Can someone please let me know the proper way to include `packaging` (the Python library) so that it'll build on the build farm as well?

Here is the build farm log for reference:
http://build.ros2.org/job/Cdev__ament_virtualenv__ubuntu_bionic_amd64/26/console

and the source code repository:
https://github.com/esol-community/ament_virtualenv

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340615/how-do-i-include-the-python-%22packaging%22-library-on-build-farm?/) by [max-krichenbauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/44322/max-krichenbauer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-12-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS 2 is targeting Python3 only. `python-packaging` refers to the Python 2 package.
The rosdep key should be `python3-packaging` (the same applies to all `python-*` dependencies in you `package.xml`.

If the key doesn't exist in [rosdep](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/python.yaml), you can contribute it following [these instructions](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#rosdep-rules-contributions)

HTH

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2019-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [max-krichenbauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/44322/max-krichenbauer/) on 2019-12-24**:
Thank you for your answer @marguedas !
I changed it, but now I'm getting `KeyError: 'python3-packaging'` and `RuntimeError: Could not resolve the rosdep key 'python3-packaging'`. Any ideas why?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-12-24**:
That sounds like the key does not exist as predicted above in the answer. With links how to resolve it.

**Comment by [max-krichenbauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/44322/max-krichenbauer/) on 2019-12-24**:
I looked on index.ros.org and it seems there is no `python3-packaging`:
https://index.ros.org/search/?term=packaging&section=deps

**Comment by [max-krichenbauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/44322/max-krichenbauer/) on 2019-12-24**:
Thanks @tfoote
Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean with "With links how to resolve it."?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-24**:
@tfoote referred to these lines in the linked documentation:

> For convenience in reviewing, please comment in the PR with links to the web listings of packages such as on http://packages.ubuntu.com, http://packages.debian.org, and https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages or if a pip package pypi.python.org.

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2019-12-24**:
As @tfoote mentioned, the rosdep key for `python3-packaging` doesn't exist yet.
In my answer I provided links to the instructions to how to contribute new rosdep rules. You should follow them and contribute a new rule `python3-packaging`

**Comment by [max-krichenbauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/44322/max-krichenbauer/) on 2019-12-24**:
Thank you, now I understood.
I'll try to get the key added.